# How to work around a "quirky" JSON API with Retrofit2 and GSON converter

Tags: php, json, type-conversion, gson, retrofit

I am implementing an client for a 3rd party JSON REST API. At the client side (my project) I am using Retrofit and GSON as libraries. The server side  seems to implemented in PHP and is beyond my control, i.e. I cannot easily bugfix the server.

The server frequently response with varying actual types for the same formal type. Out of the box, I get a lot of GSON parsing/conversion exceptions during deserialization, because GSON is very fussy about correct types.

How do I make GSON more robust, when it comes to deserializing responses and type conversion? I already found the annotation `@JsonAdapter` which probably allows me to work around those quirks of the server. But as this seems to be a typical PHP problem (examples follow below), I thought that there might already be a library or facade for GSON which solves these problems.

Specifically, the server shows the following quirks:

- Boolean: Booleans in responses are reported as actual JSON boolean, i.e. `{ b : true }` and `{ b : false }`, but also as JSON numbers `0` and `1` and as literal strings `"0"`, `"1"`, `"true"`, `"false"`. In addition, a false value is also reported as `null` (no object) and the literal string `"null"`.
- Numbers: Numbers in responses are reported as actual JSON numbers, i.e. `{ n : 42 }`, but also as literal strings `"42"`. Moreover, a zero value is also reported as `null` (no object), the literal string `"null"`, `false` (boolean value) or the literal string `"false"`
- Arrays of objects: If the array is non-emtpy everything is fine. The response is `{ arr : [ ... ] }`
  and GSON happily deserializes this into a Java `List<>`. Empty arrays are the problem. The server reports empty arrays correctly as `[]` but also as `false` or `null`.

The list above is only the beginning of oddities I have encountered so far. Probably there are more of them. That's way I am hesitating to write may own adapters for GSON, because I fear that the list will soon become endless. Any libraries out there which already have implemented conversion for those typical PHP problems?

Luckily, the GSON converter only needs additional robustness for deserialization, i.e. if a response from the server is parsed into a Java object. When Java objects are serialized into JSON and sent to the server within a request, the server happily takes any type as long as PHP is able to convert it into the required type.

---

**Update**

I started writing custom type adapters `QuirkyBoolean`, `QuirkyInteger` for the plain-old Java types (`int`, `long`, `boolean`) and their OO counter parts `Integer`, `Long`, etc.
That has been easy so far.
The tricky part is to implement a generic list adapter which covers the quirks which are mentioned in item 3 (see above) and can correctly deserialize any type inside the list correctly.
My problem is Java's type erasure.
Maybe someone has a solution for the following problem?

Assume the following annotated POJOs for GSON serialiation/deserialization.

```
public class Container {
  @SerializeName("foos")
  @JsonAdapter( QuirkyListAdapter<Foo>.class )  // Note: No legal Java syntax
  public List<Foo> foos;
  
  @SerializeName("bars")
  @JsonAdapter( QuirkyListAdapter<Bar>.class )  // Note: No legal Java syntax
  public List<Bar> bars;
}

public class Foo {
  @SerializeName("str")
  public String str;
}

public class Bar {
  @SerializeName("n")
  public Integer n;
}
```

My approach for a `QuirkyListAdapter` which correctly deserializes JSON `null`, `{}`, `""` and `false` into an empty list.

```
public class QuirkyListAdapter<T> extends TypeAdapter<List<T>> {
  @Override
  public void write( @NonNull JsonWriter out, List<T> listOfT ) throws IOException {
    final Gson gson = new Gson();
    final TypeAdapter<T> typeAdapter = gson.getAdapter( T.class );  // Note: No legal Java syntax
    out.beginArray();
    if( listOfT != null ) {
      for( final T val : listOfT ) {
        typeAdapter.write( out, val );
      }
    }
    out.endArray();
  }

  @Override
  @NonNull
  public List<T> read( @NonNull JsonReader in ) throws IOException {
    final List<T> result = new ArrayList<>();
    final JsonToken peekedToken = in.peek();

    if( peekedToken == JsonToken.NULL ) {
      in.nextNull();
      return result;
    }
    if( peekedToken == JsonToken.BOOLEAN ) {
      if( in.nextBoolean() )
        throw new IllegalStateException( "Expected an empty array encoded as boolean value \"FALSE\" but found \"true\"" );
      return result;
    }
    if( peekedToken == JsonToken.STRING ) {
      final String str = in.nextString();
      if( str.equals( "" ) )
        throw new IllegalStateException( "Expected an empty array encoded as an empty string value but found \"" + str + "\"" );
      return result;
    }
    if( peekedToken == JsonToken.BEGIN_OBJECT ) {
      in.beginObject();
      if( in.peek() != JsonToken.END_OBJECT)
        throw new IllegalStateException( "Expected an empty array encoded as an empty object \"{}\", but object has attributes" );
      in.endObject(); 
    }
    if( peekedToken != JsonToken.BEGIN_ARRAY )
      throw new IllegalStateException( "Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was " + peekedToken );

    final Gson gson = new Gson();
    final TypeAdapter<T> typeAdapter = gson.getAdapter( T.class );  // Note: No legal Java syntax

    in.beginArray();
    while( in.hasNext() ) {
      result.add( typeAdapter.read( in ) );
    }
    in.endArray();
    return result;
  }
}
```

Everything works as desired, if I replace the generic `T` with `Foo` or `Bar` resp., and implement two independent `QuirkyFooListAdapter` and `QuirkyBarListAdapter`.
Even replacing `T` with `Object` is no solution, although it compiles.
However, the tricky line is `gson.getAdapter( .. )` in my quirky list adapter.
Using `gson.getAdapter( Object.class )` obviously does not return the required adapter which is required to deserialize the correct objects inside the list.

Comment: _"That's way I am hesitating to write may own adapters for GSON, because I fear that the list will soon become endless."_ -- It sounds like a false fear: the PHP side has a finite set of quirks, and the list you've provided seems to be pretty much complete. _"Any libraries out there which already have implemented conversion for those typical PHP problems?"_ -- I doubt they exist since they cannot handle all possible cases for all quirky cases, so there is no reason to "support" quirks world-wide but it's worth keeping them localized.

Comment: Simply create type adapters handling the cases you mentioned. Even if the type adapter fails for a previously unknown case, you'll get a JSON parsing exception allowing you to add another case (hoping it won't cause any problems). I think this is justified and probably the only viable solution in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need that many type adapters since you can merge the common deserialization logic into type adapters designed for each problematic literal type (just like you posted in your question) encountered from that back end.

Type adapters created independently, not in type adapter factories, usually fit simple cases. Factories provide access to the shared *context* `Gson` instance (the one you configure and then use) and provide a concrete type to build a type adapter with (this is where "T.class" can be worked around).

```java
public abstract class AbstractQuirkyTypeAdapterFactory<T, C>
        implements TypeAdapterFactory {

    protected abstract boolean supports(@Nonnull TypeToken<?> typeToken);

    @Nullable
    protected abstract C createContext(@Nonnull TypeToken<?> typeToken);

    @Nullable
    protected abstract T read(@Nullable C context, @Nonnull TypeAdapter<? extends T> delegateAdapter, @Nonnull JsonReader in)
            throws IOException;

    @Override
    @Nullable
    public final <U> TypeAdapter<U> create(final Gson gson, final TypeToken<U> typeToken) {
        if ( !supports(typeToken) ) {
            return null;
        }
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        final TypeAdapter<T> delegateAdapter = (TypeAdapter<T>) gson.getDelegateAdapter(this, typeToken);
        @Nullable
        final C context = createContext(typeToken);
        final TypeAdapter<T> quirkyAdapter = new TypeAdapter<T>() {
            @Override
            public void write(final JsonWriter out, final T value)
                    throws IOException {
                delegateAdapter.write(out, value);
            }

            @Override
            public T read(final JsonReader in)
                    throws IOException {
                return AbstractQuirkyTypeAdapterFactory.this.read(context, delegateAdapter, in);
            }
        }
                .nullSafe();
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        final TypeAdapter<U> typeAdapter = (TypeAdapter<U>) quirkyAdapter;
        return typeAdapter;
    }

}
```

```java
public final class QuirkyBooleanTypeAdapterFactory
        extends AbstractQuirkyTypeAdapterFactory<Boolean, Void> {

    private static final TypeAdapterFactory instance = new QuirkyBooleanTypeAdapterFactory();

    private QuirkyBooleanTypeAdapterFactory() {
    }

    public static TypeAdapterFactory getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean supports(@Nonnull final TypeToken<?> typeToken) {
        final Class<?> rawType = typeToken.getRawType();
        return rawType == boolean.class
                || rawType == Boolean.class;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    protected Void createContext(@Nonnull final TypeToken<?> typeToken) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    @Nullable
    @SuppressWarnings("NestedSwitchStatement")
    protected Boolean read(@Nullable final Void context, @Nonnull final TypeAdapter<? extends Boolean> delegateAdapter, @Nonnull final JsonReader in)
            throws IOException {
        final JsonToken token = in.peek();
        switch ( token ) {
        case BOOLEAN:
            return delegateAdapter.read(in);
        case NUMBER:
            final int i = in.nextInt();
            switch ( i ) {
            case 0:
                return false;
            case 1:
                return true;
            default:
                throw new JsonSyntaxException("Unhandled integer: " + i);
            }
        case STRING:
            final String s = in.nextString();
            switch ( s ) {
            case "0":
            case "false":
            case "null":
                return false;
            case "1":
            case "true":
                return true;
            default:
                throw new JsonSyntaxException("Unhandled string: " + s);
            }
        case NULL:
            return null; // TODO or false?
        case BEGIN_ARRAY:
        case END_ARRAY:
        case BEGIN_OBJECT:
        case END_OBJECT:
        case NAME:
        case END_DOCUMENT:
            throw new JsonSyntaxException("Unhandled token: " + token);
        default:
            throw new AssertionError(token);
        }
    }

}
```

```java
public final class QuirkyNumberTypeAdapterFactory
        extends AbstractQuirkyTypeAdapterFactory<Number, Number> {

    private static final TypeAdapterFactory instance = new QuirkyNumberTypeAdapterFactory();

    private static final Function<Class<?>, Number> getKnownZero = new ImmutableMap.Builder<Class<?>, Number>()
            .put(byte.class, (byte) 0)
            .put(Byte.class, (byte) 0)
            .put(short.class, (short) 0)
            .put(Short.class, (short) 0)
            .put(int.class, 0)
            .put(Integer.class, 0)
            .put(long.class, 0L)
            .put(Long.class, 0L)
            .put(float.class, 0F)
            .put(Float.class, 0F)
            .put(double.class, 0D)
            .put(Double.class, 0D)
            .put(BigInteger.class, BigInteger.ZERO)
            .put(BigDecimal.class, BigDecimal.ZERO)
            .build()
            ::get;

    private QuirkyNumberTypeAdapterFactory() {
    }

    public static TypeAdapterFactory getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("OverlyComplexBooleanExpression")
    protected boolean supports(@Nonnull final TypeToken<?> typeToken) {
        final Class<?> rawType = typeToken.getRawType();
        return Number.class.isAssignableFrom(rawType)
                || rawType == byte.class
                || rawType == short.class
                || rawType == int.class
                || rawType == long.class
                || rawType == float.class
                || rawType == double.class;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    protected Number createContext(@Nonnull final TypeToken<?> typeToken) {
        return getKnownZero.apply(typeToken.getRawType());
    }

    @Override
    @Nullable
    @SuppressWarnings("NestedSwitchStatement")
    protected Number read(@Nullable final Number knownZero, @Nonnull final TypeAdapter<? extends Number> delegateAdapter, @Nonnull final JsonReader in)
            throws IOException {
        final JsonToken token = in.peek();
        switch ( token ) {
        case NUMBER:
            return delegateAdapter.read(in);
        case STRING:
            final String s = in.nextString();
            switch ( s ) {
            case "null":
            case "false":
                if ( knownZero == null ) {
                    return delegateAdapter.read(new JsonReader(new StringReader("0"))); // TODO optimize "constant" reading or cache previously unknown zero
                }
                return knownZero;
            default:
                return delegateAdapter.fromJsonTree(new JsonPrimitive(s)); // TODO optimize bypassing the intermediate JSON element
            }
        case BOOLEAN:
            final boolean b = in.nextBoolean();
            if ( !b ) {
                if ( knownZero == null ) {
                    return delegateAdapter.read(new JsonReader(new StringReader("0"))); // TODO optimize "constant" reading or cache previously unknown zero
                }
                return knownZero;
            }
            throw new JsonSyntaxException("Unhandled boolean: " + b);
        case NULL:
            return null; // TODO or zero?
        case BEGIN_ARRAY:
        case END_ARRAY:
        case BEGIN_OBJECT:
        case END_OBJECT:
        case NAME:
        case END_DOCUMENT:
            throw new JsonSyntaxException("Unhandled token: " + token);
        default:
            throw new AssertionError(token);
        }
    }

}
```

```java
public final class QuirkyCollectionTypeAdapterFactory
        extends AbstractQuirkyTypeAdapterFactory<Collection<?>, Void> {

    private static final TypeAdapterFactory instance = new QuirkyCollectionTypeAdapterFactory();

    private QuirkyCollectionTypeAdapterFactory() {
    }

    public static TypeAdapterFactory getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean supports(@Nonnull final TypeToken<?> typeToken) {
        return Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(typeToken.getRawType());
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    protected Void createContext(@Nonnull final TypeToken<?> typeToken) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    @Nullable
    protected Collection<?> read(@Nullable final Void context, @Nonnull final TypeAdapter<? extends Collection<?>> delegateAdapter,
            @Nonnull final JsonReader in)
            throws IOException {
        final JsonToken token = in.peek();
        switch ( token ) {
        case BEGIN_ARRAY:
            return delegateAdapter.read(in);
        case BOOLEAN:
            final boolean b = in.nextBoolean();
            if ( !b ) {
                return delegateAdapter.read(new JsonReader(new StringReader("[]"))); // TODO optimize "constant" reading (caching is not possible: collections are supposed be new and mutable)
            }
            throw new JsonSyntaxException("Unhandled boolean: " + b);
        case NULL:
            return null; // TODO or empty collection?
        case END_ARRAY:
        case BEGIN_OBJECT:
        case END_OBJECT:
        case NAME:
        case STRING:
        case NUMBER:
        case END_DOCUMENT:
            throw new JsonSyntaxException("Unhandled token: " + token);
        default:
            throw new AssertionError(token);
        }
    }

}
```

The above approach implements the Template Method design pattern for all three individual cases: booleans, numbers, and arrays (JSON arrays, but Java collections, I didn't include the Java arrays adapter for brevity).

The shared logic behind them all is as follows:

- The type adapter factory checks whether it can handle the given type.
- If it can, then it asks Gson for the delegate type adapter to deal then with.
- Creates a generic type adapter that simply delegates the write operation to the original type adapter, but the read operation is specialized in each subclass where it is accessed from.
- Each read operation implements simple JSON token peeking to decide how to proceed further based on the quirks you described in your question.

Having the following JSON:

```json
{
    "booleans": [
        true,
        false,
        0,
        1,
        "0",
        "1",
        "true",
        "false",
        null,
        "null"
    ],
    "numbers": [
        42,
        "42",
        null,
        "null",
        false,
        "false"
    ],
    "arrays": [
        [
            "foo",
            "bar"
        ],
        [],
        false,
        null
    ]
}
```

the following test passes:

```java
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@ToString
final class Data {

    @SerializedName("booleans")
    final List<Boolean> booleans;

    @SerializedName("numbers")
    final List<Number> numbers;

    @SerializedName("arrays")
    final List<List<String>> arrays;

}
```

```java
public final class QuirksTest {

    private static final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .disableHtmlEscaping()
            .disableInnerClassSerialization()
            .registerTypeAdapterFactory(QuirkyBooleanTypeAdapterFactory.getInstance())
            .registerTypeAdapterFactory(QuirkyNumberTypeAdapterFactory.getInstance())
            .registerTypeAdapterFactory(QuirkyCollectionTypeAdapterFactory.getInstance())
            .create();

    @Test
    @SuppressWarnings("ReturnOfNull")
    public void test()
            throws IOException {
        try ( final JsonReader jsonReader = open("quirks.json") ) {
            final Data data = gson.fromJson(jsonReader, Data.class);
            Assertions.assertIterableEquals(
                    Arrays.asList(true, false, false, true, false, true, true, false, null, false),
                    data.booleans
            );
            Assertions.assertIterableEquals(
                    Arrays.asList(42, 42, null, 0, 0, 0),
                    data.numbers
                            .stream()
                            .map(n -> n != null ? n.intValue() : null)
                            .collect(Collectors.toList())
            );
            Assertions.assertIterableEquals(
                    Arrays.asList(
                            Arrays.asList("foo", "bar"),
                            Collections.emptyList(),
                            Collections.emptyList(),
                            null
                    ),
                    data.arrays
            );
        }
    }

}
```